# How to use ABC Extended with standard British PC keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, input-source

The ABC Extended input is fantastic for inputing several diacritics, but it only seems to assume apple's own layouts, i.e. it doesn't recognise the standard British PC layout. Is there a way to make it work with the standard British PC layout, particularly re: the symbol mismatches between the two?

Standard British PC has `shift`+`2`=`"` and `shift`+`'`=`@`.

The Apple British layout has `shift`+`2`=`@` and `shift`+`'`=`"`.

In British PC, the key left of `1` is `` ` `` `¬`, but in Apple British it is  `§` `±`.

In British PC, the key left of `z` is `\` `|`, but in Apple British it is `` ` `` `~`.

In British PC, the rightmost key of the `asdf` row is `#` `~`, but in Apple British it is `\` `|`.

Suppose I definitely do not plan to use the Apple British layout at all, but may need to work with the standard British PC layout. Is there a way to reconfigure certain things for the ABC Extended input to be compatible with the standard British PC layout?

Comment: I'm glad you got what you needed, but I still don't understand the question. The keys you describe are all correct, in both layout & mapping, for each of a British PC keyboard & a British Apple keyboard. UK PC keyboards really do have all the keys 'in the wrong places' if you're used to Apple.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's the reverse situation for me. I do not use Apple's British layout and would like to use the `ABC Extended` input of MacOS with the standard British layout. When a British keyboard is used, `ABC Extended` automatically assumes it is an Apple British keyboard and maps the keys with the Apple layout, even if the actual keyboard being used is a standard British one. `British PC` does use the standard key mapping, but it doesn't offer the same range of diacritics available in `ABC Extended`.

Comment: ABC is based on a US ANSI map, though, rather than a British ISO map - but thank you for explaining. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin it is! It's just it recognises ISO keyboards as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update -- Problem solved with [Ukelele](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele). I copied the layout of the current input source and then manually adjusted the key mappings (including the `shift` modifications etc.). It took me just a few minutes.